# Cannot infer type arguments for ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, response-entity

I am trying to return the response as string from my function using ResponseEntity but getting an error. I tried this:

```
@GetMapping(value="/getuserip")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getUserData(@RequestParam("username") String userName, HttpServletRequest request){
    String ipAddr = (request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR"));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(ipAddr, HttpStatus.SC_ACCEPTED);
}
```

When trying to return the String variable ipAddr I am getting the error. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Found the issue. It was giving the error due to me importing the wrong library for httpstatus. I should have imported org.springframework.http.HttpStatus but I imported org.apache.http.HttpStatus thus resulting in the error. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The library for `httpstatus` was giving this error in my case. Fixed it by replacing `org.apache.http.HttpStatus` with `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`.